# javac compile error

Tags: javac, compiler-errors

Trying to create a test app that imports another test package.

The test apps are listed, as is the compile cmd and the err..

The files are all in the same dir. I was able to compile the MyIncorrectnessListener.java, and the MycssErrorHandler.java with no warnings/errs.

I'm trying to figure out what's the cause of the err >>> sjsu_classes.java:33: '.' expected <<<<<

Any pointers/comments are appreciated...

thanks

the compile cmd/err

```
[root@toshiba parseapp2]# javac -Xlint -classpath '/opt/htmlunit/lib/
*:/parseapp2/' sjsu_classes.java sjsu_classes.java:33: '.' expected
import MyIncorrectnessListener;
                             ^
sjsu_classes.java:33: ';' expected 
import MyIncorrectnessListener;
                              ^
sjsu_classes.java:34: class, interface, or enum expected 
import MycssErrorHandler;
      ^

3 errors
3 warnings



/*
//      sjsu_classes.java
//
//      function handles getting the data from the sjsu course page, and returns the course page/list
//      for the given Alphabet letter. - handles ane letter at a time..
//      -the page is then returned to the calling routinne
//
//              input:
//                      args[0] - start url
//                      args[1] - term
//                      args[2] - dept
//
//              return:
//                      course page for the term/dept
//
*/
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.NameValuePair;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.*;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.*;
import org.w3c.css.sac.ErrorHandler;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;

//==my test packages
import MyIncorrectnessListener;
import MycssErrorHandler;

public class sjsu_classes {

   //public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   public void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

           // Create and initialize WebClient object
      WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3);

           IncorrectnessListener ilisten = new MyIncorrectnessListener();
           ErrorHandler ierr = new MycssErrorHandler();
           webClient.setIncorrectnessListener(ilisten);
           webClient.setCssErrorHandler(ierr);
      webClient.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
      webClient.setRefreshHandler(new RefreshHandler() {
        public void handleRefresh(Page page, URL url, int arg) throws IOException {
                           //System.out.println("handleRefresh");
                   }

           });

           // visit the page, get the form, get the btn
           String url_tmp;
           String url;
           String Term;
           String Dept;
           String tmp1;
           String tmp2;

           url_tmp="?FolderPath=PORTAL_ROOT_OBJECT.PA_HC_CLASS_SEARCH&amp;PortalActualURL=https%3a%2f%2fcmshr.sjsu.edu%2fpsc%2fHSJPRDF%2fEMPLOYEE%2fHSJPRD%2fc%2fCOMMUNITY_ACCESS.CLASS_SEARCH.GBL&amp;PortalRegistryName=EMPLOYEE&amp;PortalServletURI=https%3a%2f%2fcmshr.sjsu.edu%2fpsp%2fHSJPRDF%2f&amp;PortalURI=https%3a%2f%2fcmshr.sjsu.edu%2fpsc%2fHSJPRDF%2f&amp;PortalHostNode=HRMS&amp;NoCrumbs=yes";

           System.exit(0);
   }
```

}

=======================

```
MyIncorrectnessListener test package
--------------------------------------------
/*
//      MyIncorrectnessListener.java
//
//      function handles getting the data from the sjsu course page, and returns the course page/list
//      for the given Alphabet letter. - handles ane letter at a time..
//      -the page is then returned to the calling routinne
//
//              input:
//                      args[0] - start url
//                      args[1] - term
//                      args[2] - dept
//
//              return:
//                      course page for the term/dept
//
*/
//==handle the warnings thrown from the js functions..

package MyIncorrectnessListener;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.*;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.*;

//public static class MyIncorrectnessListener implements IncorrectnessListener
public class MyIncorrectnessListener implements IncorrectnessListener
{
  @Override
 public void notify(String arg0, Object arg1)
 {
   //System.err.println("Argument : " + arg0.toString() + ", Object :");
 }
}
```

---

```
MycssErrorHandler test package
--------------------------------
/*
//      MycssErrorHandler.java
//
//      function handles getting the data from the sjsu course page, and returns the course page/list
//      for the given Alphabet letter. - handles ane letter at a time..
//      -the page is then returned to the calling routinne
//
//              input:
//                      args[0] - start url
//                      args[1] - term
//                      args[2] - dept
//
//              return:
//                      course page for the term/dept
//
*/
package MycssErrorHandler;

import org.w3c.css.sac.ErrorHandler;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.*;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.*;

//==handle the warnings thrown from the js functions..
       //==handle the warnings thrown from the css functions..
//      public static class MycssErrorHandler implements DefaultCssErrorHandler
//      public static class MycssErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler
//      public class MycssErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler
       public abstract class MycssErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler
//      protected class MycssErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler
       {
         //@Override
         public void notify(String arg0, Object arg1)
         {
           //System.err.println("Argument : " + arg0.toString() + ",Object : ");
         }
         //@Override
               public void fatalError(SAXParseException ex)
               {
                       //fatals.add(ex);
               }
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your java files have to be in a directory that matches their package names, so you have to place 
MyIncorrectnessListener.java in a directory named MyIncorrectnessListener, MycssErrorHandler.java in a directory named MycssErrorHandler and so on.

You could place them all in the same directory, but you have to remove the 'package' statement in the files.

The error you're getting is because you're only giving a package name in the import statement. You should import something specific, or everything, from a package. Change it to

```
import MyIncorrectnessListener.MyIncorrectnessListener;
```

or

```
import MyIncorrectnessListener.*;
```

Or if you don't place your files in any packages, you don't need any import statements.